# Linux sched folder is empty

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

When I do `ls /usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-38-generic/include/linux/sched` I get the following results:

```
deadline.h  jobctl.h  prio.h  rt.h  sysctl.h  task.h
```

There are obviously some files missing when I look at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/include/linux/sched

Now in my project I want to use the `signal.h` file, but it tells me `fatal error: linux/sched/signal.h: No such file or directory` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not asking good questions?  What distro are you using?

Comment: Kubuntu `17.10` with `Linux 4.10.0-38-generic` kernel

Comment: Kernel tree for 4.10 version: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/v4.10/include/linux/sched. There is even one file lesser than in your system.

Answer (score 2):

`<linux/signal.h>` was moved to `<linux/sched/signal.h>` in the 4.11 kernel, so you need to conditionally include one or the other depending on the kernel version:

```
#include <linux/version.h>

#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(4,11,0)
#include <linux/signal.h>
#else
#include <linux/sched/signal.h>
#endif
```